# CSS animation and on click sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need your help.
I have a suggestion eg "Web Developer" and 3 images.
The first image (test1) left and the third (test2) image right hand will be stable.
In the second image (test3) middle I want to do animation.
I want to do the following. First, the three images will have opacity 0. Second, when the user clicks the proposal will then hear the sentence, and the first impression will be one opacity and after 2 seconds to become the other two images opacity 1 and the second image makes animation to the right to go to the image bumped Tuesday.
I make the CSS but I don't good JS. Can you please help me?

```css
.test1image{
  max-width: 10%;
  margin: 4% 0 3% 30%;
}
.test2image{
  max-width: 15%;
  margin: 8% 0 3% 20%;
}

/*// Star: Element to animate //*/

.test3image{
  max-width: 15%;
  margin: 2% 0 3% -36%;
  animation-name: test3motion;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

/*// Keyframes //*/
@keyframes test3motion{
  from{ transform: translateX(20px)}
  to{ transform: translateX(230px)}
}


.sntc-img {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sntc-img--show {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<audio id="sntc-audio">
    <source src="../../fsound/fs1/s1/sntc.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    
    <div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
      <span class="sntc">Web Developer</span>
    </h1>
    <style>
    .sntc:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    <img class="test1image " src="../../fimages/images/test1.png" alt="test1 Image">
    <img class="test2image " src="../../fimages/images/test2.png" alt="test2 Image">
    <img class="test3image " src="../../fimages/images/test3.png" alt="test3 Image">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why bother adding a code snippet if you arent going to provide an example of what you tried?

Comment: where are your HTML and JS attempt ? :)

Comment: Please place everything you have, think this is not usefull to help you with.

Comment: @GCyrillus, I put HTML. But I don't write JS because I don't know good :(